# How to determine UIViewAnimation hierarchy view. Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have 2 animations that get triggered by pressing 2 different buttons. How can I determine which one I see first when they are literally occupying the same space and are on top of each other. Is there some code I can use to determine the hierarchy of what UIImageView is shown first?

Here is an example of what I am dealing with. I have a "lightning" image and a cloud image.

```
//Lightning



@IBAction func lightningOne(sender: UIButton) {

    self.darkCloud.hidden = false

    let lightning = UIImageView()
    lightning.image = UIImage(named: "lightning")
    lightning.frame = CGRect(x:-41, y:29, width:30, height:105)
    self.view.addSubview(lightning)

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.5, options: options, animations: {

        lightning.frame = CGRect(x: -45, y: 34, width: 30, height: 105)

        }, completion: { animationFinished in

            self.darkCloud.hidden = false
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
                self.view.addSubview(lightning)
                lightning.frame = CGRect(x: 41, y: 34, width: 30, height: 105)

                }, completion: { animationFinished in
                    self.darkCloud.hidden = false
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
                        self.view.addSubview(lightning)
                        lightning.frame = CGRect(x: 41, y: 35, width: 30, height: 105)

                        }, completion: { animationFinished in
                            lightning.removeFromSuperview()
                            self.darkCloud.hidden = true
                    })
            })
    })
}
```

Here is the code I use to show the cloud.

```
 // Clouds

 func movingClouds() {

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat

    let cloud = UIImageView()
    cloud.image = UIImage(named: "cloud1")
    cloud.frame = CGRect(x: -80, y: 110, width: 78, height: 42)
    self.view.addSubview(cloud)
 UIView.animateWithDuration(140.0, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
        cloud.frame = CGRect(x: 350, y: 110, width: 78, height: 42)
        }, completion: nil)
 }
```

How can I make sure the lightning image shows up behind the cloud when I trigger it and they happen to cross each other?